# Ways to further optimise the code for PLUS MULTIPLY (codechef)

Tags: c, algorithm

While solving the code for the problem [Plus Multiply](https://www.codechef.com/DEC19B/problems/PLMU) on CodeChef, I tried to solve it using binary search, but my solution gives a TLE.

I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(int a=0;a<t;a++)
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int arr[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        int s=0,j,k,f,m,mm;
         (n%2==0)?(mm=n/2+1):(mm=n/2+1);

        for(j=0;j<mm;j++)
        {
            f=n-j-1;
            for(k=j+1;k<n-1;k++)
            {
                m=n-k-1;
                if((arr[j]*arr[k])==(arr[j]+arr[k]))
                s++;
                if((arr[f]*arr[m])==(arr[f]+arr[m]))
                s++;
            }

        if((arr[j]*arr[k])==(arr[j]+arr[k]))
            s++;        
        }
      printf("%d\n",s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Kindly suggest me on how to improve the time complexity of the above code.

Comment: Side note: `int arr[n]` is not standard. Only some compilers accept it.

Comment: This question is from an ongoing [contest](https://www.codechef.com/DEC19B/problems/PLMU).

Comment: contest has ended on 16th

Comment: Ah, my bad. I read the bar above.

Comment: This question was already analyzed and answered on SO.  Remember to search before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your solution, the code looks to me as of complexity O(n^2).

But, as per the given constraints, the question expects me to solve it in O(n) time complexity.

The property, `ab = a+b` is special and exclusive only to `0` and `2`.

Therefore, just by finding the number of pairs of 0's and 2's.

And it can be calculated using combinations.

Have a look at the following code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int LL;

int main(){

    int t;
    cin>>t;

    while(t--){

        int n;
        cin>>n;

        LL z = 0; //Zero count
        LL t = 0; //One count

        while(n--){

            int x;
            cin>>x;
            if(x==0){
                z++;
            }
            if(x==2){
                t++;
            }
        }

        cout<<((z)*(z-1LL)/2LL) + ((t)*(t-1LL)/2LL)<<endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Time Complexity: O(N)**